# converting raspberryPi4 to a USB UVC device mimicking a USB camera

Tags: raspbian, usb, camera, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have a raspberyPi4 with Raspabion OS (Debian Bullseye) in it and i am willing to convert it to a USB-UVC device mimicking a USB camera so that whenever i connect it the host machine(PC in this case) it should be detected as a USB Camera by the host machine.One point to be noted is that i have not any physical camera to the raspiberry Pi instead i have some prestored video and want to stream those videos over USB .

Mentioning the above point specifically as most blogs that i found like[David Hunt](http://www.davidhunt.ie/raspberry-pi-zero-with-pi-camera-as-usb-webcam/) one and [showmewebcam](https://github.com/showmewebcam/showmewebcam) are when a camera attached to your Pi and i tried them without the camera ending up the Host machine not even recognizing the Pi as any device and giving the standard Popup 'USB Device not recognized' on Windows (Linux also fails to recognize) . I am connecting the RPi by USB cable between the type-C power port of Rpi and PC USB-A/USB-C port. I am new to to raspberryPi.Can anyone suggest how to do it ?

Thanks in advance .

EDIT:When tried using the 'showmewebcam' image for raspberryPi4 version v1.91 i am getting error in even getting the image work on my RPi4.
Just adding the snap of the point where the screen is stuck.(bare with the quality though!).Can Anybody help with that please.
[image]

Comment: This has been done with the Zero, which could provide you with a starting point: https://hackaday.com/2021/06/24/a-pi-usb-webcam-that-was-born-to-boot-quick/  Note that is about forwarding data from an actual camera on the Pi, but this should not be too big an obstacle.

Comment: Hi @goldilocks , Thanks for reviewing .I have added the error in the 'EDIT' section in actual question which i am getting with the 'showmewebcam' image as mentioned in that blog.Will highly apreciate if can help with that .